# Problem with implementing abstract property in Matlab

Tags: matlab, oop, abstract-class

In Matlab (2017b) I'm trying to implement a superclass with a yet undefined abstract property.

```matlab
classdef Class_Test1
    properties (Abstract=true)
        obj
    end
end
```

Subclasses should then implement this property and restrict it to a certain class, e.g.:

```matlab
classdef Class_Test2 < Class_Test1
    properties
        obj@double = 123;
    end
end
```

`a = Class_Test2;` now throws an error:

```
The property 'obj' restriction defined in class 'Class_Test2' must match
the property definition in base class 'Class_Test1'.
```

Is there no way to specify the class / type of `obj` in the implementation of the abstract class or am I missing something?

In the end I would like `obj` to be abstract in `Class_Test1` to implement several subclasses, which will hold objects of different classes in `obj`.

Any help appreciated ...

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB classes are weird... or in any case very different from what you expect from a class if you've learnt about classes in any other programming language.

One aspect of MATLAB is that it's an interpreted language. Stuff is evaluated when executed, not when compiled. So code doesn't always need to make sense.

So, we can solve your issue like this:

```matlab
classdef (Abstract) foo
   methods
      function c = getclass(in)
         c = class(in.obj);
      end
   end
end
```

The function `foo.getclass` seems to not make sense, since `foo` doesn't have a property `obj`. But because `foo` is abstract, we're never going to have an object of class `foo` on which we'll call the `getclass` method. Whenever `getclass` is called, it'll be a derived class. So, if we want to use this `getclass` method, we need to make sure that the derived class has a property `obj`:

```matlab
classdef foo_uint8 < foo
    properties
        obj@uint8 = uint8(1);
    end
end
```

It is now possible to call `foo_uint8.getclass`:

```matlab
>> a = foo_uint8;
>> a.getclass
ans =
    'uint8'
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so after looking into this further it seems that this is a deliberate limitation based on the design of Matlab. I'm not too familiar with OOP in other languages but would be interested to learn if this is an general OOP fundamental or rather Matlab specific.

As a workaround I have come up with the following solution:

```matlab
classdef (Abstract) Class_Test1 < handle
    properties
        Obj
    end
    properties (Abstract = true, Constant)
        ObjClass@char
    end
    methods 
        function set.Obj(obj_in,in)
            if isa(in, obj.ObjClass)
                obj_in.Obj = in;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

... and the implementation ...

```matlab
classdef Class_Test2 < Class_Test1

    properties (Constant)
        ObjClass@char = 'double';  % Define the allowed class here ...
    end

end
```

I would still be interested to learn about other possible solutions.

Comment: In C++ you can't do this either. You can have virtual methods, where derived classes change the behavior, but the types must all be identical. But MATLAB uses "duck typing" like Python, so you might not need to declare `obj` in the superclass at all. Just make sure each derived class has one `obj` property.

Comment: I need to declare ```Obj``` in the superclass because I also declare methods, which operate on ```Obj``` without relying on its type. Thus, ```Obj``` is defined as abstract but without a type in the superclass.

Comment: If you do it this way, I would have the `set.Obj` throw an error when it gets an invalid input, instead of silently ignoring it (which could lead to hard-to-diagnose bugs): `if ~isa(in, obj.ObjClass); error('invalid input type for Obj: %s', class(in); end`. That would make the behavior more like the property type restriction, too.

Comment: Re: "I need to declare Obj in the superclass because I also declare methods, which operate on Obj without relying on its type." This isn't actually true in Matlab! In a superclass, you can refer to properties that are defined _only_ in subclasses; as long as they're public, it'll still work. (As long as you don't need to instantiate and use the superclass directly, instead of using subclasses that define those properties.)

Comment: ... I have dropped extended error checking for the sake of brevity.
As for using of properties in superclass methods, which are actually not defined in the superclass: It would never have occured to me that this would be possible ... very interesting.